# Substitute keystroke

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, keyboard-events

I am trying to intercept a keystroke, and substitute it with a different character. I have been able to intercept the key being pressed, as well as perform some extra operations. Now I need to hold the key being pressed if it matches one of the ones I am watching, and insert a different character. Here is the code I have right now:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    //Keys that are being watched to be switched out
    NSArray *keysToWatch = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"c",@".", nil];


    // register for keys throughout the device...
    [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask
                                           handler:^(NSEvent *event){
                                               //Get characters
                                               NSString *chars = [[event characters] lowercaseString];
                                               //Get the actual character being pressed
                                               unichar character = [chars characterAtIndex:0];
                                               //Transform it to a string
                                               NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&character length:1];
                                               //If it is in the list, start looking if Keynote is active
                                               if ([keysToWatch containsObject:[NSString stringWithString:aString]]) {
                                                   //DEBUG: Print a message
                                                   NSLog(@"Key being watched has been pressed");
                                                   //Get a list of all running apps
                                                   for (NSRunningApplication *currApp in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]) {
                                                       //Get current active app
                                                       if ([currApp isActive]) {
                                                           //Check if it is Keynote, if yes perform remap
                                                           if ([[currApp localizedName] isEqualToString:@"Keynote"]){
                                                               //DEBUG: Print a small message
                                                               NSLog(@"Current app is Keynote");


                                                               if (character=='.') {
                                                                   NSLog(@"Pressed a dot");
                                                                   //I want to post a different character here
                                                                   PostKeyWithModifiers((CGKeyCode)11, FALSE);
                                                               }
                                                               else if ([aString isEqualToString:@"c"]) {
                                                                   NSLog(@"Pressed c");
                                                               }




                                                           }
                                                           else if ([[currApp localizedName] isEqualToString:@"Microsoft PowerPoint"]){

                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                   }
                                               }




                                               }
                                               ];
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

void PostKeyWithModifiers(CGKeyCode key, CGEventFlags modifiers)
{
    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);

    CGEventRef keyDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, key, TRUE);
    CGEventSetFlags(keyDown, modifiers);
    CGEventRef keyUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, key, FALSE);

    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, keyDown);
    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, keyUp);

    CFRelease(keyUp);
    CFRelease(keyDown);
    CFRelease(source);
}
@end
```

My problem is that I am not able to stop the original keystroke. Please keep in mind that I am completely new at Obj C, so let me know if there is anything that I can do better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs for `+[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:):

> Events are delivered asynchronously to your app and you can only
>   observe the event; you cannot modify or otherwise prevent the event
>   from being delivered to its original target application.

You would have to use a [Quartz Event Tap](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html) for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am completely lost. Could you give me a quick explanation or example? as I said I just started with ObjC

Answer (score 0):

So, after a LOT of digging around, I found a way to do this using Quartz Event Taps [here](http://brianlipkowitz.tumblr.com/post/4881199383/quartz-event-taps). Thanks to @Ken Thomases for pointing me in the correct direction. I then combined my code with the one explained in this article and voilà, it works.